# LAN Multiplayer problems in Empire: Total War on Mac

Tags: macos, empire-total-war

I am trying to play Empire: Total War Gold Edition (purchased on the Mac App Store) on two different Macs (one with 10.9.5 and one with 10.8.5) using the `Local Multiplayer` feature of the game.

Whenever we try to launch a sea battle, we are able to select our ships, and go the battle, where we are able to position our ships, but when we try to start the battle, we are prompted with an error of a desync (I don't know the exact wording).

The only solution I have found after Googling around for over an hour was to mirror the graphics settings between the two installs, which we did (on multiple presets). We are also running the same screen resolution, and are both signed out of Game Center.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Wired or wireless?

Comment: We tried both (not wired directly, but wired to a router)

Comment: Do you know if the ip addresses are static(fixed), or dynamic?

Comment: I suggest, try static IP's.

Comment: The external IP is global, the internal IPs are static

Comment: And no port forwarding on the router. Wireless off. And just the two plugged in.

Comment: Correct. They are both plugged into the router.

Comment: No phone's or p.c's connected wirelessly either. No background downloads or torrents on the A and B Mac either. Finally, in your router settings there may be a priority list for QOS(Quality of service to my knowledge). Remove them or put Total War at the top.